# Multiprocessing for multiple cameras in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, image-processing, multiprocessing

I have multiple cameras that I'd like to read images from and do some image processing.

I tried using multithreading and created a class that manages these threads and stores data.

I want to pass these images into an image processing function. Should I use multithreading or multiprocessing or a mix?

For this example code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_proc = ImgProc()
    stream0 = Stream(0,args)
    stream1 = Stream(1,args)
    streams = [stream0,stream1]
    stream_manager = StreamManager(streams,img_proc)
    stream_manager.start_streams()

    while True:
        stream_manager.process_images()
```

The img_proc obj is a class containing functions of the image processing

The start_streams() spawns multiple Thread objects that capture image frames from the streams list and stores the data in an array of queues in StreamManager.

Q1: Is the ImgProc class functions running on a process or a thread if I were to loop through the array of queues and process each of them?

Q2: should I use multiprocessing to stream each camera instead and have a multiprocessing.Array of collections.deque to share data with a separate img processing Process?

Q3: if i initialize another object in Stream class constructor, say x = DummyList. then I append a 1 to x. will stream0 and stream1 both share DummyList since threads share the same memory space? Or would they just be separate objects with only 1 of them having x = [1] and the other having x = []

Comment: keep it simple. one thread per camera. synchronous reading and processing. done. no queues, no other complications.